# Valgrind, invalid read, fgetc

Tags: c, valgrind, fgetc, memcheck

Good evening everybody.

I have written a function that is checking values that come from a stream by analyzing each character. If the character has the value of a specific sign the code should do something deeper in the program.

Everything works fine but Valgrind is complaining about a used fgetc function. I don't understand why.

```
==12681== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12681== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12681== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12681== Command: /tmp/3RKi4ZeFa74f-a.out tests/15_defaultFitting output/ausgabe_15_defaultFitting
==12681== 
==12681== Invalid read of size 4
==12681==    at 0x4EA69E1: getc (getc.c:38)
==12681==    by 0x400B58: checkUp (1441398601.c:36)
==12681==    by 0x402453: main (1441398601.c:891)
==12681==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==12681== 
==12681== 
==12681== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==12681==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==12681==    at 0x4EA69E1: getc (getc.c:38)
==12681==    by 0x400B58: checkUp (1441398601.c:36)
==12681==    by 0x402453: main (1441398601.c:891)
==12681==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==12681==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==12681==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==12681==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==12681==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==12681== 
==12681== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12681==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12681==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 568 bytes allocated
==12681== 
==12681== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12681== 
==12681== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12681== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Below there is my code:

```
31: void checkUp(char *filename)
  32: {
  33: datei = fopen (filename, "r");
  34: int h = 0;
  35: int control = 0;
  36: while((control = fgetc(datei)) != EOF)
  37: {
  38:    if(control == '\n')
  39:    {
  40:       h++;    
  41:       }
  42:          if(h>2) 
  43:          {
  44:             fprintf(stderr,"Error: Die Eingabedatei darf nur zwei Zeilen haben.\n");
  45:             abbruch = TRUE;
  46:             break;
  47:             }
  48:    if(control == '-')
  49:    {
  50:       fprintf(stderr,"Error: Keine negativen Zahlen bitte.\n");
  51:       abbruch = TRUE;
  52:       break;
  53:       }
  54:     if(control != ' ' && control != '\n')
  55:     {
  56:        if((control != 97 && control != 98 && control != 102 && control != 110 && control != 119) && (control > 57 || control < 48))
  57:        {
  58:           fprintf(stderr,"Error: Formatierungsfehler oder falsche Eingabe. Bitte prüfen Sie Ihre Eingabe.\n");
  59:           abbruch = TRUE;
  60:           break;
  61:           }
  62:           }
  63:    }
  64: fclose (datei);
  65:   }
```

If somebody can give me a hint what the reason for Valgrind's message is, I would be very gratful. I'm out of ideas. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should we *guess* where `datei` comes from? And perhaps you should *check* the result of that `fopen` for NULL before assuming it worked?

Comment: Sorry! It is a global variable: FILE *datei = NULL;

Comment: As it is apparently opened, used, closed, and no other user-defined function is invoked from this code that may access it, perhaps ponder *if* it should be global at all. Regardless, *check your IO results*. Don't just assume they worked: Assumption is the mother of all...

Comment: Since `fgetc()` is in the standard library (and therefore is unlikely to have easy-to-trigger bugs), and its only input is its single `FILE *` argument, it stands to reason that it fails because the argument is `NULL` (or otherwise invalid).  This is exactly what will happen in your code if `fopen()` fails, and there is a whole host of reasons why `fopen()` might fail.

Comment: As an aside, `if((control != 97...` would be more readable as `if((control != 'a'...` etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone. WhozCraig: Checking the IO results solved the problem. Thanks again.